# Melody with only notes C, G, D, A

Tags: melody, cello

Is there any well-known melody that only contains the notes C, G, D and A? I'm learning to play the cello, so far practicing only playing on open strings and would love to be able to play a melody.

Comment: It's not just the note names, it's the octave in which they are, So your tune won't sound too good, as the notes are spread out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. The only thing similar to using only those open strings - that I can think of - is a tune based on only the interval of a fifth - any two adjacent strings on the cello, but try the `G` and `D` - which is the "Winkie Chant" of the flying monkeys from the Wizard of Oz. I couldn't find any music notation so this description must suffice...

[image]

...the tonic (first) could be the `G` and the dominant (fifth) would then be the `D`.

```
Title   Over the Rainbow: The Wizard of Oz as a Secular Myth of America
Author  Paul Nathanson
Publisher   SUNY Press, 1991
ISBN    0791407098, 9780791407097
```